# how can i filter the data to only show specific product_type

Tags: php, mysql

```html
$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
 
$x = "";
$construct = "";  
    
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND product_type LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    
}
?>
```

im currently trying to implement search engine on this data view. im going to try and use a dropdown menu for the user to view which type of product.
i've been using mysql and it works fine. but now what im trying to do is change it to mysqli and now it all went wrong

```html
<?php
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
 $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM produk2 ORDER BY id ASC WHERE $construct " );
        if ($results) { 
 
        //fetch results set as object and output HTML
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
     echo '<div class="product">'; 
            echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
     echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/'.$obj->product_img_name.'"></div>';
            echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
            echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
            echo '<div class="product-info">';
     echo 'Price '.$currency.$obj->price.' | ';
            echo 'Qty <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />';
     echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
     echo '</div></div>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's wrong? What error is thrown?

Comment: lol, wait i update my query, that query shows everything on my database. ill update the mysql version and i need help on how to change it to mysqli

Comment: its okay, already solve it, i just need to remove ORDER BY id ASC then it all works just fine :D